# Angular is returning "TypeError: Cannot read property" when using regular expressions

Tags: regex, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to extract a youtube id form the input provided. the output is fine but i am receiving this error `TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null`

```
$scope.Message.color = 'green';
$scope.Message.content = 'sss';
$scope.Videos.youtubeAdd=true;

$scope.$watch('item.url', function() {
    var re = /(\?v=|\/\d\/|\/embed\/|\/v\/|\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/;
    value = $scope.item.url;
    value = value.match(re)[2];
    $scope.item.url =   value;
});
```

Comment: Add calls to `console.log` to make sure `$scope.item.url` and `value.match(re)` aren't null.

Answer (score 0):

please see here http://jsfiddle.net/K39DU/ that should helps. You can check if are any matches before you take second element from array

var app = angular.module('app', []);

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I38q5Ad5GaM';
    var re = /(\?v=|\/\d\/|\/embed\/|\/v\/|\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/;
    value = $scope.url;

    $scope.arrays = value.match(re);

    if ($scope.arrays && $scope.arrays.length > 1) {
        $scope.id = $scope.arrays[2];
    }


});
```